# How to get response from blockchain.com by using wss in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, python-asyncio

I try to connect to [blockchain.com](https://blockchain.com) websocket by using [this API](https://www.blockchain.com/ru/api/api_websocket). I use [websockets library for Python](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). When I connect by using the interactive client method, I have a success. But when I try to connect by using  my Python script, I have no any response from server socket. This is my script:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv") as client:
        print(await client.recv())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This is what I have in terminal when I use interactive client, and I expect to see it when I run my script:

```
Connected to wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv.
>
```

Comment: I would suggest that the output "Connected to wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv." is just from the interactive client (whatever this is) and not actually send by the server. So if you want to have this too simply add a `print("Connected to wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv." )` to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SteffenUllrich mentioned in comment this text is displayed by `interactive client` - it is not message received from server - and you have to use own `print("Connected to wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv.")` to display it.

And if you want to `recv()` something from sever then first you have to `send()` command to server.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv") as client:
        print("[main] Connected to wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv" )

        cmd = '{"op":"ping"}'
        print('[main] Send:', cmd)
        await client.send(cmd)
        print('[main] Recv:', await client.recv())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Result:

```
[main] Connected to wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv
[main] Send: {"op":"ping"}
[main] Recv: {"op":"pong"}
```